# Covering map preserved under homotopy equivalence

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology

Given a $m-$sheeted covering map from $p:M^n\to N^n$, where $M,N$ are manifolds of dimension $n$. Suppose $M$ and $N$ are homotopy equivalent to finite CW complexes $X$ and $Y$ of same dimension $k$. Does there exists a $m-$sheeted covering map $q:X\to Y$ so that $pf$ and $gq$ are homotopic, where $f:X\to M$ and $g:Y\to M$ are homotopy equivalences?

Comment: If we get to choose X to be whatever we want, then yes- pull back along the equivalence from Y to N. If not, then no: take M=N=Y=* and take X to be a closed disk.

Comment: Dylan's X and Y are not of the same dimension, but this is easy to fix; take Y to be the wedge sum of X with a disk of lower dimension.

Comment: @DylanWilson thanks!!